# Windows 10 continuum issue

Tags: windows-10, display, display-settings

So I have one of those convertible 2-in-1 laptops, the Lenovo Flex 3. Lately, when I put it into sleep mode, something weird happens. The screen is black, the keys light on and it doesn't appear to wake up. 
The only thing that seems to work is plugging in an external monitor. Even then the laptop is in tablet mode and trying to adjust the display settings so that monitor 1 (the laptop monitor) is turned on doesn't work. The only thing that works is a hard reset.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although is may seem obvious what you want, we are not able to read your mind. Can you please ask a specific question? Unless you do, you may not get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Internet search for "Lenovo Flex 3 does not wake" gave several results. From there, I checked the Lenovo community forums. It seems this is a [BIG PROBLEM WITH FLEX 3 1570 Won't wake up from sleep mode](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-100-305-500-Edge/BIG-PROBLEM-WITH-FLEX-3-1570-Won-t-wake-up-from-sleep-mode/td-p/2167132).

I don't know what exact model you have, but it appears to be an issue with the graphics driver.

Assuming you have posted because you want to know how to fix it, this is what you should do:

> To Get the correct Graphics Driver from Intel Support:
>
> 1. Right-click mouse on screen background and select Graphic Properties to bring up Intel HD Graphics Control Panel.
> 2. Click on Options and Support. Then on the left-hand panel click on Support.
> 3. Click on Download latest Intel Graphics Driver.
> 4. On the Welcome To Support page, Click on Download Drivers and Software.
> 5. Click on Automatically update your drivers. This will download Intel's Update Utility.
> 6. After downloading the Utility, run it to scan your PC and it will determine which drivers have new versions available.  You then have
>      the option of downloading the new drivers and installing them.
>      Installing the new Graphics driver will solve the "Unable to wake from
>      Sleep Problem."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The version I have is the flex 3 15 inches version with an Nvidia 920m. Would the Intel driver still be relevant?

Comment: No, but the point is there are issues with drivers. Look for updated Nvidia drivers. If this is still under warranty, call Lenovo.

Comment: Turns out the laptop had both an Intel driver and an Nvidia driver. The instructions for manually updating the Intel driver worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with similar trouble with my Flex 3-1480. I had lenovo tech support remote into my laptop and update the display driver manually. However, this didn't worked. I read on other forums about updating the BIOS and I exactly did that and voila it worked!!

No issues on waking up from sleep! But I guess Windows update somehow changes the BIOS settings and I will have to keep updating my BIOS every time I run into this issue.